# prove equality of series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This is analogous to [Proof of a generating functions formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2739643/proof-of-a-generating-functions-formula), but I need a concrete explanation of the induction part.

Prove that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {n+k \choose k}x^n = \frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}}
$$
for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and all $x \in (-1,1)$.

My attempt:

When $k=0$, this reduces to geometric series: $\sum_{0}^{\infty}x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$.

When $k \geq 1$, suppose $S(k) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {n+k \choose k}x^n = \frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}}$, how can I show that it holds for $S(k+1)$?

In particular, how can I show that $S(k+1) = S(k)+xS(k+1)$?

Comment: Try $k=0$ first. & note the $+1$ !

Comment: If you had $k=1$ then the right hand side denominator would be $(1-x)^2$, not $1-x$.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Could you help with the induction part? I can't get why $S(k+1) = S(k)+xS(k+1)$.

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
S(k)+xS(k+1)= 1+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{n+k}{k} x^{n} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+k+1}{k+1} x^{n+1}.
\end{eqnarray*}
reindex the second sum $n+1 \rightarrow n$, note that the limits of the sum & exponent of $x$ become the same as the first sum, and then use 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{n+k}{k} + \binom{n+k}{k+1}=\binom{n+k+1}{k}.
\end{eqnarray*}